# Difficulty applying Picard's iteration on homogeneous equation of the type $\dot x(t) = Ax(t), x_o(t) = x_o$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Given

$$\dot x(t) = Ax(t)$$
$$ x_o(t) = x_o$$

We obtain equivalent integral equation 
$$x(t) = \int_{t_o}^t Ax(s) ds + x_o$$
$$x_o(t) = x_o$$

Then approximate $x(t)$ via $\{x_n\}$, so we obtain
$$x_{n+1}(t) = \int_{t_o}^t Ax_n(s) ds + x_o$$
$$x_o(t) = x_o$$

Assume that $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x(t)$, and wlog let $t_o = 0$ we can then apply Picard's iteration such that

$n=1:$ $$x_1(t) = \int_0^t Ax_o ds_1 + x_o$$

$n=2:$ $$x_2(t) =  \int_0^t Ax_1 ds_2 + x_o =  \int_0^t A\left(\int_0^t Ax_o ds_1 + x_o\right) ds_2 + x_o$$

$n=3:$ $$x_3(t) =  \int_0^t Ax_2 ds_3 + x_o =  \int_0^t A\left(\int_0^t A\left(\int_0^t Ax_o ds_1 + x_o\right) ds_2 + x_o\right) ds_3 + x_o$$

...

How can this mess be simplified so that we can obtain

$$x(t) = e^{At}x_o$$

as our final solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use that

$$\int_0^t ds = t ; \int_0^t\int_0^{s_1} ds_2 ds_1 = \frac{t^2}{2} ;\ldots; \int_0^t\int_0^{s_1}\cdots \int_0^{s_n-1} ds_n ds_{n-1} \ldots ds_1 = \frac{t^n}{n!} $$

Take one or two steps to see the sum $e^{At}$ then formalize by induction.

For example:

$$x_2 (t)  = x_0 A^2 \frac{t^2}{2} + Ax_0 t + x_0 = x_0 \left(\frac{(At)^2}{2} + At + 1 \right)$$

Comment: Why should we integrate over the previous dummy variable every time we nest an integral?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: prove by induction that 
\begin{align*}
x_n(t)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{t^kA^{k}x_0}{k!}.
\end{align*}